# How to initialize a multidimensional jagged array of mixed types in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

How do I enter this array as an input for Java.

```
[[1, 5, [2, 3]], [2, 3, []], [3, 3, []]]
```

I've tried

```
int[][][] arr = {{1,5,{2,3}}, ...};
int[][] arr = ...
```

but both do not work.  How do I do this???  Is the only way to do this is via a List???

Comment: did you see this example in the documentation or why do you think this would work? Have you read the documentation about array initialisation?

Comment: Actually your array is not array of just `int` but array of array as well. So you have to try `ArrayList` which can store objects of different classes.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? This seems like an XY problem

Comment: It's this problem off https://leetcode.com/problems/employee-importance/description/ .  I'm trying to do it with ArrayList but was confused because I was wondering if that would be considered a int[][].  I'm now wondering if I'm suppose to put <Integer> or <Employee>

Comment: Java arrays are homogeneously typed, so you'd have to make it `Object[]`.

Comment: Look at the method stub they give you. It accepts a `List<Employee>`

Comment: @GBlodgett How do I make an <Employee> lol??  Do I have to make some Employee class?

Comment: @guestuser9202 Yes. They give you the basis of the class

Comment: @GBlodgett I see public List<Integer> subordinates;  However, how do I put this List of Integers in it now?  Do I just List<Employee> arr = new ArrayList<>(); then if I try arr.add({1,5,{2,3}}); I get an error